# Joomla - Two Factor Authentication - Opt-in

Tags: joomla, two-factor-authentication, joomla3.2

Currently, it appears that Joomla has an opt-in 2FA implementation.
Is it possible to force our users to use 2FA login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two factor authentication is typically used for Administrators and up.  Setting it up can be tricky (the user needs to download and initialize the google app), so each user should do it individually.

Since you're creating the users (you need a Super User to add new users) you could create a new user group with access only to com_users, so they may set up two-factor authentication; then once they do manually move them to a higher group which will give them full access to the administrator.

You will also need to create a template override so the admin users won't be able to change the two factor authentication preferences.